# Android setContentView not being applied

Tags: android

Hi I'm this is a reask of a previous question just because i wasn't clear before. i have  a json feed that consists which i found the length of the array in it. as it should it produces one. but what i'm trying to do is if a second item were to be added that feed another layout would need to be used.

so i currently have a string that contains the String value of YES this is then sent in an intent to anther activity this is placed inside an if statement that says if x = Yes then use layout1 if x = no use layout2.

the problem i'm having is when i put a string in the if statement and log it it works but when i put setContentView in and it forces the app to close why?

here is my code

in the 1st activity

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
String json = reader.readLine();

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);


JSONObject objData = obj.getJSONObject("data");

JSONArray jArray = objData.getJSONArray("structure");

leagueCount = jArray.length();


if (leagueCount == 1){                   
   teamFeedStructure = "YES" ; 
}        
if (leagueCount == 2){
   teamFeedStructure = "NO" ; 
}
```

now the intent sent

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);

mainIntent.putExtra("leagueCount", teamFeedStructure);

firstActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);

firstActivity.this.finish();
```

now in the second Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.introact);

    String leagueCount = getIntent().getExtras().getString("leagueCount");

    //String leaguecount = String.valueOf(leagueCount);

    Log.v("lc", leagueCount);

    if (leagueCount == "YES"){

        String one = "one";
        setContentView(R.layout.introact);

        Log.v("lc", one);       
    }

    //if (leaguecount == "2"){

       //setContentView(R.layout.introact);
    //}
```

The Error

```
04-23 21:53:34.455: W/dalvikvm(954): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.uk.fantasticmedia.TheEvoStikLeague/co.uk.fantasticmedia.TheEvoStikLeague.IntroActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at co.uk.fantasticmedia.TheEvoStikLeague.IntroActivity.onCreate(IntroActivity.java:45)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-23 21:53:34.465: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You must compare strings using the .equals method:  if (leagueCount.equals("YES"))

Comment: If its blank run your code again and read the stacktrace again. Is IntroActivity the first activity with the Json or the second one?

Comment: introActivity is the second activity. essential i have a loading activity that loads the json and then passes it to introActivity the purpose for this is if the json feed has more than 1 the layout requires an extra button so i have created two layouts this is just to future proof the app because at the moment it only has 1 but could have 2 in the future

Comment: I've edited my answer. I don't think you were sending anything. i.e. what does this line `Log.v("lc", leagueCount);` print out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use == to compare strings == will compare the memory location you need to do:

```
 if("1".equals(leaguecount))
```

[Top Ten Errors Java Programmers Make](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/toptenerrors.html) (See number 7 )

Comparing your hard coded string `"1"` with the equals method (instead of `something.equals("1")` also saves you having to do a null check\

---

I think your problem is your sending `null` and not actually initialising your string. After you parse your JSON I would do it like this:

Here's a rewrite:

```
teamFeedStructure = "NO";
if (leagueCount >= 2){
   teamFeedStructure = "YES" ; 
}
```

Then your other activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String leagueCount = getIntent().getStringExtra("leagueCount");
    Log.d("lc", "Received league count of:"+ leagueCount);

    if ("YES".equals(leagueCount){
        setContentView(R.layout.introact);
        Log.d("lc", "Using league count of 2 or more layout");
    }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.introact_something_else);
        Log.d("lc", "Using default layout");
    }
 }
```

Comment: i added this and it still force closes the app

Comment: If you changed your onCreate to look exactly like that, there is no possibility of it force closing. The only thing is you wouldn't have this `R.layout.introact_something_else` layout. What is the error?

Comment: however i did get a log of league count being 1 and it logged using default layout but it's just not loading the layout

Comment: i added what you put the only thing i changed was R.layout.introact_something_else to R.layout.introact_v2 which i have could it be something iside the introact_v2 thats causing it

Comment: i just changed R.Layout.introact_v2 to R.Layout.introact and it worked so must be something wrong with the the layout file so. thank you very much for your help really appreciate it

Comment: although i just used another layout i know works and it forced closed it again

Comment: when i name them both .introact it works  but as soon as a change the bottom layout it force closes

Comment: Because something you are referencing in `findViewById` cannot be found in the second layout. You should really read your stack traces.